# How can I recover a deleted file in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, file-recovery

I accidentally deleted a scanned document and can't find in Recycle Bin.  I followed [this article on Microsoft's website](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/recover-lost-or-deleted-files) but no previous versions were found.

Is there other methods I can use without installing any recovery software?

Comment: No, you will need recovery software. There's recovery software which doesn't need to be installed though, which is either "portable" or can run from a live medium (E.g. USB/ DVD).

Comment: ^^^ And try not to write to the drive before attempting recovery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is only one fool-proof method of recovering an accidentally deleted file without using any third-party tools:

**Recover the file from the backup you made beforehand.**

If you don't have a backup, then you would need to use recovery software to get the file back. A couple examples would be:

- [Recuva](http://downloads.techradar.com/downloads/recuva)
- [DMDE](https://dmde.com/download.html)

The problem is that these programs aren't 100% guaranteed to be able to recover the file, because of the way Windows and NTFS file tables work:

Once a file is deleted, the "record" in the file table that tells the operating system where that file lives on the hard drive is removed, letting Windows know that space is available to fill with other stuff. The file might still be there, but Windows may have overwritten the space with new a new file(s).

You have a better chance at recovery if there has been less time from the moment of accidental deletion and less writing to the drive during that time. Windows may not have overwritten the space where that file lived.

---

In your situation, and correct me if I'm wrong, but a scanned document technically already has a backup available: *the paper original*.